# Eevee Rendering: not ever object is getting rendered

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

I got a render problem in my file. There is basicly a Camp and I want to make a camera move through it to show every thing. There are also small animations. Now I am stuck at the point where I want to render the whole thing. At first I want to use eevee and switch maybe then to cycles.

All Objects are shown in the viewport shading but when I start the animation rendering as pngs moste of my objects aren't shown. I tried to solve this problem but can't find the proper solution. What am I doing wrong
(all the wooden houses and stuff are based on blenderkit assets)

[image: this is how it looks in the viewport shading]
[image: and this is the first frame I get when I render it with eevee]

all the wooden houses and stuff are based on blenderkit assets

had to put it in a google drive because the file is 60MB big

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YHeeHKqFiHTYWYHk3vkzc988jubblYMb?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried it and sadly it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you disabled some objects in render mode:

[image]

The camera icon means: enable or disable in render.

You can change the visibility of your render icon if you click on filter and then the corresponding icon:

[image]

result after enabling LP Plank (i just enabled that and assumed you made that mistake some more times...)

[image]

Viel Glück!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please click in the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you! Thanks!